# Convert macro to function call with assignment operator

Tags: c++, c

We have macro that assigns a float to a memory address.

```
#define GP(Indx)    *(pfGVal+##Indx##)
```

where pfGVal is a pointer to a shared memory of float values.

Assignment is

```
GP(SOME_Index) = 1.23f;
```

While this works fine it has some obvious issues. We would like
to call a function instead to check limits etc. but do not want
to change the syntax, because we have to keep the code backward
compatible working with legacy code.

I read into std::function, lambdas etc. but couldn't find any way
to solve this problem.

Comment: What are `Assignment` and `is`?

Comment: C or C++? C++ has classes with overload-able assignment operator, C does not. These are different languages.

Comment: You _could_ assign to a function call if it returns a reference to something...

Comment: @NathanOliver Wrongly placed prose.

Comment: The use of ## in the macro does not seem like valid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
float& GP(std::size_t Indx) { return pfGVal[Indx]; }
```